# Swap column values across rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

i want to update emp last name and first name. means first emp name should be update to fifth emp like.

```
id,firstname
1,john
2,pall
3,kevin
4,Alan
```

result should be

```
id,firstname
1,kevin
2,Alan
3,john
4,pall
```

Comment: Please explain how the ordering is supposed to work? You've mentioned `5th emp` and last name, but aren't showing either.

Comment: i have lacks of records in one table. i have to update the one column records in jumble (any order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited information you gave us, the solution would look something like this:

```
update emp
   set firstname = case id
                    when 1 then (select firstname from emp where id = 3)
                    when 2 then (select firstname from emp where id = 4) 
                    when 3 then (select firstname from emp where id = 1)
                    when 4 then (select firstname from emp where id = 2)
                 end
where id in (1,2,3,4);
```